# How to pre-fetch a component for later in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that takes a long time to load, when the user loads my homepage and when there is noting else left for the browser to do, I want to pre-fetch this heavy component in the background so that when the user clicks the link to load it, it's there instantly.

Is there a way to do this eager pre-fetching for later in React?

Comment: This is called "code-splitting", see https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html If you're using `react-router` there's explicit support for this aswell.

Comment: Is the component itself that is heavy ? or something it does on mount, like fetching remote data ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it's a component that loads the mapbox library and draws the map on the page. I believe it's the drawing that makes it heavy (takes 5 or so seconds to render the map).

Comment: If you are using mapbox-gl library and want to lazy-load the component there are some caveats to that. I will post an example that solves the issue.

Comment: Try using: https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal to keep it rendered. Or you can keep: `display: none;` on it to render it normally without displaying it.

Comment: @ZacharyHaber thanks, I was able to lazy load the component which prevented some of the UI legginess which I initially intended to solve using this, will look more into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code splitting implementation when using mapbox-gl with react-app using `React.lazy` and `Suspense`

```
import React from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

// IMPORTANT Please include the css required for mapbox-gl in the same file
import 'path-to-vendor-css/_mapboxgl.external.css';

function MyMapbox() {
   // your map implementation
}
```

Now lazy-load the component where you want to use it.

```
import {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';

const MyMapbox = lazy(() => import('path-to-the-mapbox-component'))

// usage
//fallback prop displays "loading..." content

<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
  <MyMapbox/>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: i have blank canvas when try this